# Plot graph using latitude and longitude in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am still new to python and I am analyzing a dataset related to the world airport network and I would like to visualize the graph related to that network but plotting the nodes based on their latitude and longitude values (each node in the graph has these two values)

Below I put a screen of the attributes of a node in the graph that I obtained using NetworkX

[image: Node]

Is there a way or a library that allows me to do this in python?

I would like a graph similar to this

[image: worl_airport_map]

Comment: If I've understood, you want to take each airport's latitude and longitude (stored in a JSON file) and plot a point at e.g. `x=lon, y=lat`. Where are you struggling? Extracting the location, or plotting the points? Maybe edit your question to include what you've tried.

Comment: It might also be more helpful if you add the example JSON code to your question in place of an image of it.

Comment: @Steve I was complicating my life unnecessarily, NetworkX allows me to do what I want to do